# Google places API counts about 22 times more than 1 request

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

I recently noticed that I'm getting about 22 times the requests as I should be getting on the Google API console which let to some unexpected charges. Below is the code I am using to get details about hospitals near an area. I need the name and street address.

```
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey("MYAPIKEY")
        .build();

NearbySearchRequest req = PlacesApi.nearbySearchQuery(context,
        new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(Double.valueOf(lat), Double.valueOf(lon)));


PlacesSearchResponse resp = req.keyword("hospital").type(PlaceType.HOSPITAL).radius(42000).await();

if (resp.results != null && resp.results.length > 0) {
    for (PlacesSearchResult r : resp.results) {
        try {
            PlaceDetails placeDetails = PlacesApi.placeDetails(context, r.placeId).await();
            AddressComponent[] address = placeDetails.addressComponents;
        } catch (com.google.maps.errors.NotFoundException nfe) {

        }
    }
}
```

What is causing this to register about 22 times more requests?

Comment: is possible cause of loop on finding details? place serach 1 time + loop for place details?

Comment: You execute 1 nearby search request that gets up to 20 items in the response, after that you execute 20 place details requests in for loop. This should result in 21 requests in your developer console. Do you see different number?